# fstream and file pointer moving

Tags: c++

Ive been trying saving the file pointer location before resetting it and then set it back but things don't seem to work as I want.

I came up with:

```
fstream f;

// open...

long long p = f.seekg(); // Save previous location

f.seekg(std::ios::beg);  // Set ptr to the file beginning

// Work with the file...

f.seekg(p);              // return ptr to the previous location (p)
```

If I try to print the fileptr location after the following commands the value is -1..
Is it because I reached EOF when I worked with the file?
And if I cant set it back to the previous location with seekg, what other alternatives I should consider?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long long p = f.seekg();
```

Cannot even compile, you probably mean `tellg`.

```
f.seekg(std::ios::beg);
```

this is wrong; `seekg` has two overloads, one that accepts a position in the stream, and one that accepts an offset from some particular position, specified with an enum. The `std::ios::beg`/`cur`/`end` only work with this other overload. So, here you want

```
f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
```

And, most importantly, if your stream is in a dirty state (eof, fail, bad) the seek won't have any effect. You have to clear the status bit first, using `f.clear()`.

By the way, if you want to go safe storing the file pointer location, you should use the type `std::istream::streampos`. So, summing it up:

```
std::istream::streampos p = f.tellg(); // or, in C++11: auto p = f.tellg();
// f.clear() here if there's a possibility that the stream is in a bad state
f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
// ...
f.clear();
f.seekg(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

`tellg` returns the file position indicator:

```
std::istream::pos_type p = f.tellg();
//                           ^^^^^
```

Comment: Yea, but the compiler doesn't seem to care when I use it the third time (f.seekg(p)). The file indicator position still remains -1

Answer (score 0):

Reset the flags first, if you encounter the EOF

```
f.clear();                 // clear fail and eof bits
f.seekg(p, std::ios::beg);
```